# How to set limit of persisting records?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, dql

How to solve the issue of adding new records to the table, but with a limit based on the number of already existing records in table?

I have table with some location nested one in the next. I want to allow user to add new location and sublocation but no more than a certain amount.

This is how my location entity, looks like:

```
  /**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
 */
private $barCode;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\LocationType")
 */
private $locationType;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Location")
 */
private $locationParent;
```

I add new location in this way:

```
 switch ($name) {
       case 'Location':
            $locationType = $this->locationType(LocationType::SUBLOCATION);
            $locationParent = $this->locationParent($id);
            $lastBarcode = $this->lastBarcode($locationType, $id);

            if ($lastBarcode) {
                $parentBarcode = $locationParent->getBarcode();
                $lastBar = $lastBarcode->getBarcode();
                $bar = $lastBar[-1];
                $a = $this->checkLocationLimit($locationParent, $lastBar);

            } else {
                $parentBarcode = $locationParent->getBarcode();
                $startValue = 'A';
            }
            break;

        case 'SUBLOCATION':
            $locationType = $this->locationType(LocationType::SUBSUBLOCATION);
            $locationParent = $this->locationParent($id);
            $lastBarcode = $this->lastBarcode($locationType, $id);

            if ($lastBarcode) {
                $parentBarcode = $locationParent->getBarcode();
                $lastBar = $lastBarcode->getBarcode();
                $bar = $lastBar[-1];

            } else {
                $parentBarcode = $locationParent->getBarcode();
                $startValue = '1';
            }
            break;
        }  
ETC.
```

And then:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfLocation; ++$i) {
         if ($name == 'Location') {
            if ($lastBarcode) {
                $barcode = $parentBarcode . ++$bar;
            } else {
                $barcode =  $parentBarcode . $startValue++;
            }
        } elseif ($name == 'Sublocation') {
            if ($lastBarcode) {
                $barcode = $parentBarcode . ++$bar;
            } else {
                $barcode = $parentBarcode . $startValue++;
            }
ETC.


$location = new Location();
        $location->setLocationType($locationType);
        $location->setLocationParent($locationParent);
        $location->setBarcode($barcode);

        $this->entityManager->persist($location);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
```

It give me barcode of locations like:

```
1 - 1A - 1A1

2 - 2A - 2A2

etc.
```

But I want to allow user to add no more than 25 sublocations of location (A-Z) and no more subsublocations of sublocation than 10 (1-10).

I made something like that to count number of already existing child location like this:

```
        $parent = $locationParent->getId();
        $firstChar = $lastBar[0];
        $allSublocations = $this->locationRepository->createQueryBuilder('location')
              ->andWhere('location.barcode LIKE :firstChar
                     AND parent.id LIKE :locationParent')
               ->leftJoin('location.locationParent', 'parent')
               ->andWhere('parent.id like :locationParent')
               ->setParameters(['firstChar' => $firstChar.'%', 'locationParent' => $parent])
               ->getQuery()
               ->getArrayResult();
```

And I don't know how to check how much new records user wants to add, and keep it to be less than I wrote (25 for locations with letter naming and 10 for number naming).

Comment: Add a subLocations collection to the parent, then use a custom Validator class to check the sublocation collection size.

Comment: @programmer-man Ok, thx for response! But i can't contrive how this Validator should looks like, i check documentation but that did't clear my problem, can I ask you for some more advices?

Comment: You can more info in https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: @programmer-man I figured out how to make custom Validator and it works fine but if I could ask another question, let's assume there is already 25 Locations in DB (It can be max 26 only), User want to add another 10 locations so 1 of this locations is succesfull added and another not (because of limit). With this validator, when User want to add too many locations, form will not allow him to do this, throwing flash. I want to insert max possibly records and inform user about it (how many locations was succesfull added and how many not). Any tips how should I do it?

Comment: If you mean adding sublocations, then you can create a Validator for that collection field of the parent location. In that Validator, you can call the entitymanager to check the DB.